# Bands that sound similar to "I See Stars"?

Tags: rock, electronic-music

I want to know the bands which sound similar to I See Stars.Thanks

Comment: http://www.last.fm/music/I+See+Stars/+similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like the band Attack Attack! [Attack Attack!- Stick Stickly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDzt6yI3Dw8)

the wikipedia entry for electronicore has a list of other bands you might also like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronicore